# ran into a memory leak when trying to pass an array of data from JAVA to MATLAB via putVariable

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-engine

I am trying to do MATLAB calculations via JAVA using MatlabEngine
But I ran into a memory leak when trying to transfer an array of data from JAVA to MATLAB via putVariable.
The process occupies all available memory and swap and I don't understand where to dig...

JAVA code example

```
public class MemoryLeaks {
    @Test
    public void test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        String[] options = {"-nojvm"};
        for (int a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {
            MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab(options);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                double[][] data = new double[600000][2];
                eng.putVariable("data", (Object)data);
//                eng.eval("[h,pValue,stat,cValue,mles] = jcitest(data)", NULL_WRITER, NULL_WRITER);
            }
            eng.quit();
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
            System.out.println("cycle "+a);
        }
    }
}
```

memory consumption after a short period

jcmd $pid VM.native_memory detail.diff

```
....
-                  Internal (reserved=32808312KB +5151601KB, committed=32808312KB +5151601KB)
                            (malloc=32808276KB +5151601KB #31150 +4405)
                            (mmap: reserved=36KB, committed=36KB)

-                     Other (reserved=10KB, committed=10KB)
                            (malloc=10KB #2)

-                    Symbol (reserved=1519KB, committed=1519KB)
                            (malloc=1159KB #16352)
                            (arena=360KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=1275KB +204KB, committed=1275KB +204KB)
                            (malloc=258KB +108KB #3843 +1716)
                            (tracking overhead=1018KB +96KB)
....
[0x00007fd9f8c49382] jni_GetDoubleArrayElements+0x162
[0x00007fd73acb871f]
[0x00007fd73acba487]
[0x00007fd73acba968]
                             (malloc=32807813KB type=Internal +5151563KB #6999 +1099)
```

```
while true
do
  cat /proc/175836/smaps | grep -i 'Pss:' |  awk '{Total+=$2} END {print "PSS: " Total}'
  sleep 5
done
```

```
PSS: 27240963
PSS: 27775401
PSS: 28225477
PSS: 28267110
```

tried different versions of java, different scopes of variables, closing and not closing the MATLAB process, clearing memory in MATLAB via "clear all".

Comment: My best guess is that matlab is not releasing the object you gave to Java. But you will have to ask matlab support, not SO.